# find overlaps or completely nested ranges and flag them

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'region_name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 'start' : [1913, 46430576, 52899183, 58456122, 62925929, 65313395, 65511483, 65957829], 'stop' : [90207973, 90088654, 90088654, 74708723, 84585795, 90081985, 90096995, 83611443], 'chr':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]})
```

I would like to find overlaps or completely nested ranges in successive `start-stop` ranges after sorting by smallest `start` to largest `start` if the `chr` is identical for successive `start-stop` pairs.

Output should look like this:

[image]

So far I have:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['chr', 'start'], ascending=[True, True])
for i in range(1,len(df['region_name'])):
    if df['critical_error'][i] == True:
        continue
    for j in range(0,i):
        if df['start'][i] <= df['stop'][j] and df['stop'][i] <= df['stop'][j] and df['chr'][i] == df['chr'][j]:
            df['overlap'][i] ='no overlap, nested with region %s' % df['region_name'][j]
            break
        elif df['start'][i] < df['stop'][j] and df['chr'][i] == df['chr'][j]:
            df['overlap'][i] = 'overlap within region ' + df['region_name'][j]
        else:
            continue
```

Its missing a bunch of the cases above, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hello! So this is not a python implementation, but I noticed you have genomic data and [bedtools](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/merge.html) is actually a really powerful, highly efficient tool that can do what you're looking for. You can then follow it up with a quick script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the part:

> ... if the chr is identical for successive start-stop pairs.

I still wrote you some code which is at some points identical to your given table. If you clarify your point I may update that answer. Maybe it still helps you already and you are able to fit the missing piece in:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'region_name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 'start' : [1913, 46430576, 52899183, 58456122, 62925929, 65313395, 65511483, 65957829], 'stop' : [90207973, 90088654, 90088654, 74708723, 84585795, 90081985, 90096995, 83611443], 'chr':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]})

# store texts for each row in that list
overlaps_texts = []

# iterate over all rows
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # extract entries' data
    start, stop, ch = row[1:4]

    # Check if I am completely inside (nested into something)
    # Note that this will always return indexers where each entry if True or False
    # So nested will be something like [False, False, True, ...] where True means
    # that start > start_other AND stop < stop_other (="I am nested")
    nested = ((start > df.loc[:, 'start']) & (stop < df.loc[:, 'stop']))

    # hanging out left
    overlap_1 = ((stop > df.loc[:, 'start']) &
                 (stop < df.loc[:, 'stop'])
                 )

    # starting before stop of other but ending after (hanging out right)
    overlap_2 = ((start < df.loc[:, 'stop']) & (start > df.loc[:, 'start']))

    # one of both overlaps good
    overlap = (overlap_1 | overlap_2) & ~nested

    # identical chr? I didnt get that part. That may be different for your application
    overlap &= df.loc[:, 'chr'] == ch
    nested &= df.loc[:, 'chr'] == ch

    # generate text
    text = ''

    # check if any nestings
    if np.any(nested):
        nested_indices = [*filter(lambda x: x[1], zip(range(len(nested)), nested))]
        text = "I am nested within: "
        region_names = []
        for index, _ in nested_indices:
            region_names.append(df.iloc[index,0])

        text += ", ".join(region_names)+"; "

    # check if any overlaps (obviously one can write that more DRY), since it repeats the pattern from above
    if np.any(overlap):
        overlap_indices = [*filter(lambda x: x[1], zip(range(len(overlap)), overlap))]
        text += "I overlap: "
        region_names = []
        for index, _ in overlap_indices:
            region_names.append(df.iloc[index,0])
        text += ", ".join(region_names)

    if text == '':
        text = 'I am not nested nor do I overlap something'

    overlaps_texts.append(text)

df.loc[:, 'overlap'] = overlaps_texts

print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
   start                       ...                                                                 overlap
0      1913                       ...                              I am not nested nor do I overlap something
1  46430576                       ...                                     I am nested within: A; I overlap: G
2  52899183                       ...                                  I am nested within: A; I overlap: B, G
3  58456122                       ...                         I am nested within: A, B, C; I overlap: E, F, G
4  62925929                       ...                         I am nested within: A, B, C; I overlap: D, F, G
5  65313395                       ...                         I am nested within: A, B, C; I overlap: D, E, G
6  65511483                       ...                         I am nested within: A; I overlap: B, C, D, E, F
7  65957829                       ...                              I am not nested nor do I overlap something
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code so far. By identical chr I mean for the last row (last start-stop pair) chr is 2 whereas rest of the pairs its 1, so no overlap or nesting with the rest, which you did output in your answer)

Comment: Ok, the code will only count a nesting / overlapping if and only if it also has the same chr field. If thats what you wanted, there you go. If you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Sorry but I am not being able to reproduce your solution. I get an `invalid type comparison` error at line `nested = ((start > df.loc[:, 'start']) & (stop < df.loc[:, 'stop']))`. I also edited  `df` in original question to include `region_name` column

Comment: You have to adopt to the changed data frame then:     start, stop, ch = row[:3] has to be changed to your new layout.

Comment: I edited the sample to work with your NEW data as given in the thread

Comment: Thanks Ric, I copy pasted your solution as is. Firstly, `*` next to `lambda` at both locations gives me a syntax error. Is the asterisk supposed to be there? Secondly, when I remove `*` and run the code, I get `TypeError: invalid type comparison` at the same line `nested = ((start > df.loc[:, 'start']) & (stop < df.loc[:, 'stop']))`

Comment: Yes, the asterisk belongs there. But you seem to use Python 2.  You can replace the two expression with the pattern: `overlap_indices = [x for x in zip(range(len(overlap)), overlap) if x[1]]` if youre in python 2

Comment: Had to tweak it a bit and got it working. Thank you so very much!!

Comment: Glad I could help out :)